# Unknown Databaseformat? Visual Studio connection to MS Access .accdb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to Connect a simple little Microsoft Access file with my Visual Studio.

So I've opened Server Explorer and clicked on Connect Database -> Microsoft Access Database File -> Select my `TestDb.accdb` file and then clicked on Test Connection.

Error Message pops up:

> "Unknown Databaseformat + [path to my access file]".

I have already clicked on "Advanced" but I cant change the Provider. SOS

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you create the connection, did you click on advanced:

Here:
[image]

And then here:

[image]

Note the list of Access choices (ACE or JET).

If you don't see ACE, then you likely don't have the ACE database engine installed. You can find + download a copy of ACE here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

You don't need ACE for a mdb file, but for accDB files, you do have to install ACE.

Note that you have a choice of x32 (x86) bit version, or a x64 bit version. Since most installs of office are x32, then choosing the x32 bit version from above link to install is your best bet.

You can test/try if you have a working copy of ACE, and test/try both a x32 bit version, and a x64 bit version of .net with this sample of mine here:
https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=B18A57CB5F6AF0FA&resid=B18A57CB5F6AF0FA%21101313&authkey=AB-I3mHVZhLmd2Q

The above has a tiny .net x32 and .net x64 bit version. So you can try both if you wish to see if your machine has ACE installed. Note the option to select ACE or jet as

it has this main screen:
[image]

So you can quick try the above .exe (its in a zip file). It is very tiny, and will thus test/check if you can open the accDB file in .net. If you can, then your .net project should work ok - if not, then you have to install ACE.